# Get the color of a cell through a LibreOffice Calc formula

Tags: libreoffice, desktop-background

I would like to get the color (background or foreground) of a particular cell in a formula (in LIBREOFFICE CALC) so that the result depends on that color.

I would be grateful for tips on how to accomplish this.

Comment: "Access the color"? From where? Command line, bash/python/perl script, php,  LibreOffice Calc macro, ... ? The `.odt` format is documented.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19313486) help?

Comment: The only way is with a macro, as in the comment by @tohuwawohu.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main methods of achieving this:

1. By using Conditional Formatting
2. Using the `STYLE()` function with numbers or text.

With acknowledgements to [This reference](https://linux.m2osw.com/setting-color-cell-libreoffice-calc-depending-cell-value) from *The Linux Page* which explains the methodologies to apply in both cases.

LibreOffice Documentation:
[Conditional Formatting](https://help.libreoffice.org/4.3/Calc/Conditional_Formatting)
[STYLE() function](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Documentation/Calc_Functions/STYLE)
[COLOR()](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.2/en-US/text/scalc/01/func_color.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id1102201617201921)

Comment: Unfortunately, I expressed myself in a misleading way.
The color should influence the result value of the formula.
E.g.: red => 0; green => 1; etc.